# Can't connect to mongodb Atlas with typeorm

Tags: mongodb, express, typeorm

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database with typeORM in an express project but I'm getting a 'Unescaped slash in userinfo section' error. My password doesn't have any special characters that need to be encoded so I don't know what's going on.

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm" 

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mongodb",
    host: "mongodb+srv://username:password@database.cluster.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    synchronize: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    logging: true,
    ssl: true,
    entities: [
        "src/entity/*.ts"
    ],
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
})
```

```js
"use strict";

import express from "express";
import cors from 'cors';
import "reflect-metadata";
import { AppDataSource } from "./data-source";




AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true // this will allow cookies to be sent accross domains
  }));


  app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 8080");

  })

})
```

the error I'm getting :

```js
    return callback(new MongoParseError('Unescaped slash in userinfo section'));
                    ^
MongoParseError: Unescaped slash in userinfo section
    at parseConnectionString (D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:627:21)
    at connect (D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:283:3)
    at D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:284:5
    at maybePromise (D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:692:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:280:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:426:22)
    at D:\Personal\jamboit\backend\node_modules\typeorm\src\driver\mongodb\MongoDriver.ts:249:38
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace **host** params to **url** in DataSource options

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mongodb",
    url: "mongodb+srv://username:password@database.cluster.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    synchronize: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    logging: true,
    ssl: true,
    entities: [
        "src/entity/*.ts"
    ],
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
})
```